# Get a historical version of a model

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm working with Django 1.10 and I have two models like these:

```
class Model1:
    name = models.CharField()

class Model2:
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1, default=get_default_model1)
```

The `get_default_model1` function must get a specific instance of `Model1` (with a specific name, for example) or create it if it doesn't exist. The problem is that this function imports `Model1` and will also be used in a migration: this means that such migration will probably break when `Model1` is modified because it will import the new version of `Model1` instead of the version it needs at that time (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#historical-models) for a better explanation of this problem).

When doing a `RunPython` operation in a migration you have access to historical versions of a model via the `apps` argument, but this is not the case.

I have written the following code to manually create the historical version of my model:

```
from django.db import models, connection
from django.db.migrations.loader import MigrationLoader

def get_default_model1():
    loader = MigrationLoader(connection)
    apps = loader.project_state(list(loader.applied_migrations)).apps
    Model1 = apps.get_model('app', 'Model1')
    return Model1.objects.get_or_create(
        name=settings.DEFAULT_NAME,
        defaults={'name': settings.DEFAULT_NAME}
    )[0].pk
```

But in some migrations it fails with `django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Node ('default', '0004_auto_20160423_0400') not a valid node`. It seems to be related to replaced migrations of a third-party dependency.

Is there a better way of getting a historical version of my model or accomplishing what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: can you explain why you need a historical model? Such a model will be out of sync with the database so creating foreign keys etc may not be possible

Comment: I tried to explain why in the second paragraph, but it may not be clear enough. I need the historical version because the function is the default value of a field, thus it will create a new migration for that model. When that migration runs, it needs to see the version of the model that's in sync with the database at that moment, which may not be the same as the latest version in the case where the model suffered more changes afterwards.

Comment: Can't this field be set to null? that would make life a lot easier

Comment: Ha, well it would make it easier alright, but the whole purpose of this question is to disallow null values for that field.

Comment: Ook that sheds a little more light. But still why you need to know what the model was like? Your current code shows you returning a model instance not a model class

Comment: can you clarify the point raised in my last comment please

Comment: This function will run from a migration, but migrations can't simply import the current version of models. They need to import a version that matches what they see in the database at that point. If my function simply imports `Model1`, it may have a field that doesn't exist yet for the running migration, resulting in a database error.

Comment: You can use the MigrationLoader to load a specific project state: as long as you know the app name and migration name/number, you should be able to find that. (I did this the other day: unfortunately that was the part of the code I didn't blog about).

Answer (score 0):

You can define `get_default_model1` function as:

```
def get_default_model1(Model1):
    default_model = Model1.objects.get(...)

   return lambda: default_model


class Model1:
    name = models.CharField()


class Model2:
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1, default=get_default_model1(Model1))
```

And then use it in migrations:

```
Model1 = apps.get_model("<your_app>", "Model1")
Model2 = apps.get_model("<your_app>", "Model2")

for model2 in Model2.objects.all():
    if not model2.model1:
        model2.model1 = get_default_model1(Model1)
```

I know that this doesn't look the prettiest, especially the part where you have to manually set the default value, but you get the right model injected into the function, so your goal is achieved.

Comment: As I explained, I don't have access to the `apps` registry. The function will be called from a normal `AlterField` operation.

Comment: I don't see where is the problem. The actual function that will be used is the lambda. So you don't need to modify it, just create a wrapper that will create it in the way you want.

Comment: I understand, but where do I get the `apps` registry from in such a way that it has the historical version of my models? In your example you just have an `apps` variable but you don't show it how to build it.

Comment: Ok, i see what is the problem. I think that the best solution would be to make the migration in 3 steps: set default value to `None`, populate `model1` field in data migration, set default value to your function. Do you think this is feasible?

Comment: But I end up in the same situation I am now: in the third migration I will be using a function that directly imports `Model1`, meaning the migration will break once `Model1` changes again in the future.

Comment: But at that moment all relations will already be set, so the function won't be called, just set.

Comment: Oh, mmm, it might work if Django actually checks if there are rows it needs to update before actually updating, which I doubt. Let me check it just in case.

Comment: It doesn't work. Django doesn't check if there are rows that need updating (makes sense) so the function executes anyway.

Comment: You doesn't want to write migrations aware code outside of migrations. First there is a lot more space for errors, and second it is slower. What if you take approach with 3 migrations and mock the function in third migration? With this trick, even if function will be called, only dummy replacement of the function would run.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could use that as a workaround if there is now way to achieve what I want. I agree that it would be slower too, but that doesn't really matter in this particular case. Thank for your time!